# How to apply Apache SetEnvIf directive only to non-existing files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, setenv

I am trying to restrict access to my website using AuthUserFile except the root path.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/$" allow_access=true

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow_access
```

However, I ran into an issue when files like robots.txt also get protected.

For some reason the following directives **do not** work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=allow_access]

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow_access
```

Is there any way to restrict access to /any/path/here/ except the home page (/) and physically existing files such as robots.txt and favicon.ico?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done elegantly using the [IF directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) and [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

```
<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
  SetEnv allow_access
</If>

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow_access
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bit tricky but this combo of `mod_rewrite` and `mod_setenvif` works:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if file or directory doesn't exist then forward to /deny
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ /deny [L]

# set env variable deny_access if URI is /deny
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/deny$" deny_access

# block access if env variable deny_access is set
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=deny_access
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your solution. However, this doesn't work in my case.
The problem is that there is a rewrite rule in vhost that rewrites URI to query for index.php (usual practice for User-Friendly URL). 

At this moment I need to allow access to / and existing files (such as robots.txt), but need to deny access to /any/path/here/.

This is indeed tricky. That's why I need help from Apache experts. :)

Comment: Can you post your existing rule so that I can reproduce it on my end and provide you an updated answer.

Comment: Please refer to the second block (that do not work).

Comment: That I have already seen before posting my answer. You mentioned about `that there is a rewrite rule in vhost that rewrites URI to query for index.php (usual practice for User-Friendly URL)` I am asking you to post that rule.